# Add an overlay to app icon with custom launcher

Tags: android, android-activity, custom-component, android-launcher

I took the following code to implement my own custom launcher:

https://github.com/fookwood/Launcher3

My goal is it to set an Bitmap or PNG file as an overlay above the normal app icon. But I can´t find the region where google is originally setting the app icon in the "All Apps View". Does somebody know where to look exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found it by myself. For everyone who wants to know it. There´s a class called IconCache.Java.

```
/**
 * Fill in "application" with the icon and label for "info."
 */
public synchronized void getTitleAndIcon(AppInfo application, LauncherActivityInfoCompat info,
        HashMap<Object, CharSequence> labelCache) {
    CacheEntry entry = cacheLocked(application.componentName, info, labelCache,
            info.getUser(), false);

    application.title = entry.title;
    application.iconBitmap = overlay(entry.icon,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.overlay_green));
    //application.iconBitmap = entry.icon;
    application.contentDescription = entry.contentDescription;
}
```